# How to set up a reverse mapping zone for a personal domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, reverse-dns, dns-hosting

I've been trying to figure out how to set up a reverse zone based on an already existing forward zone, but I keep getting an error saying `server can't find xx.xxx.xx.xxx.in-addr.arpa: SERVFAIL` whenever I try to run an IP through `nslookup`. Here's the forward zone in question:

```
$TTL    15M
@       IN      SOA     ns1.b900.et. root.b900.et. (
                     2019061200         ; Serial
                            15M         ; Refresh
                             5M         ; Retry
                           120M         ; Expire
                            600 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
@              IN      NS      ns1
@              IN      A       164.40.155.48
ns1            IN      A       164.40.155.48
b900           IN      A       164.40.155.48
```

And here's the reverse zone:

```
$ORIGIN 42.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL    15M
@       IN      SOA     ns1.b900.et. root.b900.et. (
                     2019061201         ; Serial
                            15M         ; Refresh
                             5M         ; Retry
                           120M         ; Expire
                            600 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
@       IN      NS      ns1.b900.et.  
48      IN      PTR     ns1.b900.et.
```

Running `named-checkzone` doesn't return anything, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don’t know whether it’s a general rule, but I find it’s common that reverse DNS is managed by whoever owns “your” IP range.

Comment: @MikaelH true, but here the IP addresses are in the private block of `192.168.0.0/16` (rfc1918 section 3 and rfc6761 section 6.1), so anyone is free to (locally) manage the reverse handling.

Comment: "what I'm doing wrong. " in all cases like that you need to show **exactly** what you tried, what command you entered. You have shown only part of the response, and redacted. Show real commands and outputs.

Comment: Your reverse zone (192.168.42.0/24) does not match at all your forward zone, which references `164.40.155.48`. So your question is really not clear.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Correct; I missed that the reverse zone pertained to local addresses. With split DNS there’s nothing preventing you from having a reverse zonefile for internal use, naturally.

Answer (score 2):

The reverse lookup zone is managed by the entity that manages that particular netblock, which almost certainly isn't you.

Comment: Except that this block (192.168.0.0/16) is private, hence there is no specific entity managing it (except IANA if you want)

Comment: True enough. I didn't pay enough attention to the zone in the question.